# "No Activity found to handle Intent" error when trying to save picture to external storage in Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-external-storage, save-image

I am trying to save a picture to external storage from a MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent.
I keep getting this error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE dat=content://ca.kevincook.trackmytrip.fileprovider/DCIM/default_image.jpg flg=0x3 clip={text/uri-list U:content://ca.kevincook.trackmytrip.fileprovider/DCIM/default_image.jpg} (has extras) }
```

Here is my code:

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File imagePath = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "");
                File newFile = new File(imagePath, "default_image.jpg");
                Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "ca.kevincook.trackmytrip.fileprovider", newFile);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, contentUri);
                intent.setData(contentUri);
                getContext().grantUriPermission("ca.kevincook.trackmytrip", contentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                getContext().grantUriPermission("ca.kevincook.trackmytrip", contentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

onActivityResult method:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 0)
        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {

                Uri uri = data.getData();
                GalleryAdapter.addImage(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.toString()));


            }
        }

        SaveImagePopup("Enter Picture Name");
    }
```

Activity declaration in manifest file:

```
        <activity   android:name=".MapsActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Permissions in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name = "android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true"/>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_public_path" path="." />
</paths>
```

I copied the code exactly from the android developer website:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider

I used getContext() because I'm running it from a fragment. I also tried getActivity() in its place, but that didn't work.

Comment: Does your device support camera feature?

Comment: Yes, I can take pictures and save them as bitmaps, but I can't save the full size picture to storage.

Comment: you facing issues while retrieving the image?

Comment: There is no image to retrieve, I can't save it to storage.

Comment: replace your provider_paths.xml  with the following,
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="public-files-path" path="." />
</paths>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the file provided in the manifest? If not Use it in this way

```
<provider
    android:name=".fileprovider"
    android:authorities="com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx" //Your package name
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" />
```

and can handle in on the activity result

The code in onActivityResult will be like this,

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            File out = new File(getFilesDir(), "newImage.jpg");
            if (!out.exists()) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error while capturing image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return;
            }

            Bitmap mBitmap =     BitmapFactory.decodeFile(compressedImage.getAbsolutePath());
           
           ivShowImage.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
    }
}
```